# build openssh on windows

Tags: compilation, cygwin, openssh

I am trying to build openssh on windows using cygwin, but in the **make** step I get the folowing error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/myuser/dev/openssh-5.4p1/openbsd-compat'
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wuninitialized -Wsign-compare -Wno-pointer-sign -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-builtin-memset -fstack-protector-all  -I. -I.. -I. -I./..  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -c bsd-arc4random.c
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/bn.h:132:0,
                 from ../buffer.h:49,
                 from ../entropy.h:30,
                 from ../includes.h:173,
                 from bsd-arc4random.c:17:
/usr/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:153:29: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
/usr/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:199:33: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
Makefile:26: recipe for target `bsd-arc4random.o' failed
make[1]: *** [bsd-arc4random.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/myuser/dev/openssh-5.4p1/openbsd-compat'
Makefile:134: recipe for target `openbsd-compat/libopenbsd-compat.a' failed
make: *** [openbsd-compat/libopenbsd-compat.a] Error 2
```

**./configure** worked without problems and I have openssl installed. I cannot figure out what could be wrong.

Comment: See http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-12/msg00194.html

Comment: You are right, that fixed it. If you make an answer out of it I will accept it.